# how to fix these when using neo4j_driver in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am having several problems when trying to use neo4j in nodejs at the backend.

1. The following seems fine, but I could not see any nodes in local database browser.

   ```
     var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
     var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
     var session = driver.session(); 
     session.run('CREATE (a:person {name: "aaaa")-[a:work_at]->(b:company    {type:"Inc"})');
     session.close();
     driver.close();
   ```

at the local browser

> http://localhost:7474/browser/

I tried to see these added nodes by

> match (a) return a

but nothing came out.
So, where above nodes are now? how do I know that i added something to database?

2. Since above code seems fine,  I put it inside a function in a module, called it in another module. The problem is that I got an error, how is this possible? It is the same code, OMG!

   ```
   function test() {
   var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
   var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
   var session = driver.session();
   session
     .run( 'CREATE (a:person {name: "aaaa")-[a:work_at]->(b:company    {type:"Inc"})' )
     .then( () => {
         console.log( 'add a node' );
         session.close();
         driver.close();
     })
     .catch(error =>{
         console.log( error );
         session.close();
         driver.close();
         return error;
      })
   }
   ```

I keep getting the following error. Searched everywhere, but could not fix it.

> Error: Connection was closed by server

3. How can I specify where to put my database files, name of the database file and so on?
4. I wanted to import data to noe4j from csv file. 
   Can I use 'load csv' like the following

> session.run('load csv from .....')

can I do that?
I saw every one just using 'load csv' from commend line.
If I must have to do from command line, how can I specify the path of the file?

Anyone point out what I am doing wrong? 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cypher query has a couple of major problems, and will not work.

- You omitted the `}` when assigning the `name` property to the `person` node.
- You are attempting to use the same identifier, "a", in two conflicting ways: for a node and for a relationship.

Something like this would work (I left out all identifiers, since your current query doesn't need them):

```
CREATE (:person {name: "aaaa"})-[:work_at]->(:company {type:"Inc"})
```